# Understanding an app's theme. Which fields belong to which entities?

Tags: flutter

I have trouble using themes to make my app design consistent throughout the app, even though i would love to. My sole problem with a custom theme for my Flutter app is I don't know which fields belong to which entities. In the TextTheme section of the Theme class alone there is plenty of values, which I have no clue what means. Why is there two `body` fields and four `display` fields?

[image: Fields in TextTheme]

I was wondering if someone knew a guide to the Theme's namingspace. I have looked on the web myself but could not find any satisfying infomation. I know it is a broad question, but if someone could point me in the right direction it would be great!

Comment: There is a Medium poster that is covering this at a high level. See https://medium.com/flutter-community/themes-in-flutter-part-1-75f52f2334ea

Comment: You can check out [panache](https://github.com/rxlabz/panache) from Rxlabs. It lets you generate a theme for flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more info [here](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-1-17-4182d8af7f8e), below graphic summarizes it.

> Notice that the `TextStyles` called `body1` and `body2` in the
>   Material Design specification are called `bodyText1` and `bodyText2`
>   in the Flutter `TextTheme` API.

[image]